# upgrading 27" Mac (late 2014) to an SSD Drive (samsung 850 Evo)

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, sata, upgrade

I need to know if I'll need a new SATA 3 cable or do I just plug the new drive into the existing cable?

this is the info i see.......

```
Intel 8 Series Chipset:

  Vendor:   Intel

  Product:  8 Series Chipset

  Link Speed:   6 Gigabit

  Negotiated Link Speed:    3 Gigabit

  Physical Interconnect:    SATA

  Description:  AHCI Version 1.30 Supported


APPLE HDD ST1000DM003:


  Capacity: 1 TB (1,000,204,886,016 bytes)

  Model:    APPLE HDD ST1000DM003

  Revision: AP14 

  Serial Number:    Z4Y3FKQ0

  Native Command Queuing:   Yes

  Queue Depth:  32

  Removable Media:  No

  Detachable Drive: No

  BSD Name: disk0

  Rotational Rate:  7200

  Medium Type:  Rotational

  Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)

  S.M.A.R.T. status:    Verified

  Volumes:

EFI:
  Capacity: 209.7 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
  File System:  MS-DOS FAT32
  BSD Name: disk0s1
  Content:  EFI
  Volume UUID:  0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
disk0s2:
  Capacity: 999.35 GB (999,345,127,424 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Content:  Apple_CoreStorage
Recovery HD:
  Capacity: 650 MB (650,002,432 bytes)
  File System:  Journaled HFS+
  BSD Name: disk0s3
  Content:  Apple_Boot
  Volume UUID:  9D62C737-33CD-3854-BF33-F2E2BCD972DE
```

Comment: You are not going to be able to "replace" the cable.  You have an Apple product

Answer (score 0):

You’ll be able to plug and go since it uses a SATA cable. I replaced a HDD with an SSD in a 2014 MacBook Pro a month ago and it was a breeze.

When you start it up it will go into the Apple recovery and you can reinstall the OS from there.